# The action you have requested is not allowed. even without csrf protection

Tags: codeigniter, csrf

In my codeigniter project.CSRF protection is not set true.But when I submit a form i got following error "An Error Was Encountered
The action you have requested is not allowed.".
It is my form view

```
<?php echo form_open('business/add-user',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));?>
                                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">

                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">User Name<span

                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="business_id" 
                                        value="<?php echo $business_id;?>">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name"

                                               value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" name="name"

                                               placeholder="User Name">

                                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; color: red;"><?= form_error('name'); ?></div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Email Address<span

                                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                    <div class="col-md-7">

                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email"

                                               value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" name="email"

                                               placeholder="Email Address">

                                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; color: red;"><?= form_error('email'); ?></div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Phone<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                    <div class="col-md-7">

                                        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="phone"

                                               value="<?php echo set_value('phone'); ?>" name="phone"

                                               placeholder="Phone">

                                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; color: red;"><?= form_error('phone'); ?></div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Password<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                    <div class="col-md-7">

                                        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password"

                                               value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" name="password"

                                               placeholder="Password">

                                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; color: red;"><?= form_error('password'); ?></div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit"><i

                                                    class="fa fa-check"></i> Add User

                                        </button>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            <?php echo form_close();?>
```

My controller

```
        public function add_user()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[user_login.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Phone','required|xss_clean|is_unique[user_login.phone]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('','');
    if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
    {
        $data['business_id']=$this->input->post('business_id');
        $this->load->view('admin/business/create_user',$data);
    }

    else
    {
        if($this->Business_Model->add_user())
        {
            redirect('account/business-profile/'.$this->input->post('business_id'));
        }

        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('SUCCESSMSG','User not created');
            $data['business_id']=$this->input->post('business_id');
            $this->load->view('admin/business/create_user',$data);
        }
    }
}
```

action of the form rooted as
$route['business/add-user']='admin/Business/add-user';

i.e forms action is add_user in controller
I need to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">` I'm not 100% sure if this is causing the issue.

`form_open` already adds a hidden field with the csrf token for you!

Comment: I have removed it but still error exists.In my project csrf protection is not set to true.Please let me know other situations when this error "The action you have requested is not allowed."

Comment: view source and make sure the csrf token is there? are you using ajax by chance (doesn't look like it)? if the token is there and you aren't using ajax I have no clue what the problem could be. try to make a simple form and see if that works and work forward from there.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it.Issue was action of the form I given is business/add-user.This route is configured in routes.php file.In xampp there is no issues.But in server when I submit form "The action you have requested is not allowed" error occured.So I cahnged form action into default route "admin/Business/add-user".Thus error fixed